# firing itemtap event on Ext.List

Tags: list, events, sencha-touch

I have defined a sencha List as below

```
Ext.List({
                    itemTpl: '<div class={filterClass}></div>{filterType}',
                    id: 'sFilter',
                    width: 200,
                    cls: 'sFilter',
                    grouped: false,
                    indexBar: false,
                    store: store,
                    listeners: {
                        itemtap: function (me, index, item, e) {
                            var selectedRecord = me.store.getAt(index);
                            var filterTag = selectedRecord.data.filterTag;
                            if (filterTag !== searchResultTag.Everything) {
                                var filteredResults = filterResults(filterTag, allResults);
                                //some more code
                            } else {
                                //some more code
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Items of the list are dynamically added and they dont have an "id".
I would like to fire (first item) itemtap event on the above list. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

This should allow you to grab the selected record and fire that tap event

```
  listeners: {
            itemtap: function (me, record, index, item, e) {
                var selectedRecord = index.data.filterType;
                var rec=record;

                if(rec===0){
                    alert('This is the first record');
                }else{
                    alert('This is not the first record')
                }
                       alert(selectedRecord);


        }
    }
```

Comment: but i how will i fire tap event on the first item of the list ?

Answer (score 0):

```
 listeners: {
        itemtap: function (me, index, item,record,e) {


            if(index==0){
                alert('This is the first record');
            }else{
                alert('This is not the first record')
            }
                   alert(selectedRecord);


    }
}
```

this may help you